# C++ Can virtual methods be implemented when declaring an object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm back to working with C++ after quite a long while using Java almost exclusively, so I'm hitting snags when trying to do things I could do in Java but can't in C++.

In this case, in Java I could do something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public void myMethod();
}

// -------

MyClass myObject = new MyClass(){
    myMethod()
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
};
```

In essence, I'm implementing the logic for *myMethod()* when declaring the *MyClass* object (Note that my syntax might be off).

I'm trying to find out if there's an equivalent for C++

My specific use case is a set of tests for a Server/Client architecture where the Test objects extend the base Server/Client abstract classes and implement the virtual methods controlling their behaviour. 
I need to modify this behaviour for each specific test, and it would come in handy to be able to "inline" these implementations when declaring the Test objects, rather than having to implement several variations on the Test object for each specific test.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've implemented *Smeeheey*'s answer as follows, and works like a charm

```
int main(...)
{

   class TestServer : public BaseServer
   {
      public:
         TestServer(...) : BaseServer(...){...} //Constructor

         void virtualFunction(...){...} // Extended function
   };

   TestServer testInstance(...);

   // Execute tests using testInstance object
```

}

Comment: Pretty sure the interface for a given class is locked in when you compile. The only thing after that you can do is manipulate function pointers or add *lambda* type methods that require special handling.

Comment: XY problem? Use one of the classic design patterns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually come pretty close, with an anonymous local struct/class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

void doStuffWithMyStruct(MyClass& s)
{
    s.doStuff();
}

int main()
{
    class: public MyClass
    {
    public:
        void doStuff() override
        {
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
    } s;

    doStuffWithMyStruct(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the above, the variable `s` has an anonymous type, very similar to Java. Its functions can be accessed in a reference to its base type. Live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8efc38a43b1a38e1).

Comment: Unfortunately that won't do, as the base class I'm testing should remain unchanged for the tests to have actual validity, but it's an interesting trick nonetheless.

Comment: You don't need to change the base class for this to work. Why did you think you would? I have used precisely this trick before for precisely your use case: unit testing

Comment: You mentioning structs, and using them in your example. :(

Comment: Structs and classes are the same thing in C++ (just different default access). I've changed my example to use class instead, it works exactly the same

Comment: Yep, just saw your edit, I'll see if it works in my case, thanks!
And yeah, as I said, I'm a bit rusty on C++ still, sorry for that.

Comment: Woop! Tested it and works like a charm, minus a couple caveats. Adding it to the question text.

Comment: @Oskuro Do not edit your question to add answer, either post your own or edit an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no equivalent in C++, nor could there be for the way classes are commonly used in C++.

In Java, this creates a new class type which derives from `MyClass` and overrides `myMethod()`. This works, because variables of type `MyClass` are just references, so those variables can hold references to derived classes.

In C++, variables of type `MyClass` are not references. They must be of type `MyClass`, nothing else. While it is possible for `MyClass &` to hold a reference to a class that derives from `MyClass`, the use of references (or pointers) in this case is very unidiomatic C++.